# Regex to pull date from file path

Tags: java, regex

I have a file path like so

`Folder/file_20231218.txt`

And I am stuck on what the regex would be for pulling the date of this path. My code for creating the matcher/localDate is below

```
String file = "Folder/file_20231218.txt";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String regex = ".*_(\\d{8}).*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(file);
return LocalDate.parse(dateFormatter.format(m.group()));
```

I know I could also do it like this

```
String file = "Folder/file_20231218.txt";
String subString = hi.substring(hi.lastIndexOf("_")+1, hi.lastIndexOf("."));
```

But there might be instances were I can't predict what the file might be named.

Comment: You should use matcher.find() in combination with the group like so `if (m.find()) { System.out.println(m.group(1)); }` m.group() defaults to m.group(0) which just returns the string as a whole i believe

Comment: As for why you need to use find(), based on the documentation find() "Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern." so I would say what you are doing is attempting to find the grouped match, but you havent told the matcher to start matching the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altering your provided code a bit, please see the below approach.

The regex will give you the ability to grab the date in format `yyyyMMdd` if it's between a `_` and file extension.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] dates = {
        "_20231218.txt",
        "NewFile_20231218.txt"
    };
    for (String s : dates) {
      System.out.println(getDate(s));
    }
  }

  public static LocalDate getDate(String input) {
    LocalDate date = null;

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
    String regex = "_(\\d{8})\..*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(input);

    if (m.find()) {
      String dateString = m.group(1);
      date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, formatter);
    }
    
    return date;
  }
}
```

See the [LocalDate.parse() docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter-) to find that it takes in types that interface `CharSequence` rather than [type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) `SimpleDateFormat`. Also, as experiment unit 1998X stated, `m.group()` [requires the 1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-) to refer to the matched part of the string.

Comment: This is really fragile. The first sequence of 8 digits will be picked up; for example if there are 9 digits there this will silently ignore the 9th. Some form of `_(\\d{8})\\..*` or maybe even `\\b` (word break) would be useful here. Also, your first line is referring to a now deleted answer, so I edited that away.

Comment: Thank you @rzwitserloot, I agree. The biggest uncertainty here is _"But there might be instances were I can't predict what the file might be named."_ My thought process was if the format were `yyyyMMddHHmmSS.txt` to get the first 8 digits. If we're certain the timestamp is not a part of any possible filenames and prefixed with `_`, then I'm all for `_(\\d{8})\\..*`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression looks correct, but there are a couple issues in your code .
The`Matcher` needs to find a `match` using `find()` before accessing `groups`
And you should use`group(1)` not `group()` to retrieve the matched date.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner:

```
String date = filename.replaceAll(".*_(.*)\\..*", "$1");
```

This regex matches the whole filename but captures the date part as group 1, then replaces (everything) with group 1, thereby effectively extracting the date part.

The regex:

- `.*_` matches everything up to and including an underscore
- `(.*)` matches can captures everything until the next match
- `\\..*` matches a dot and the rest of the string